# Compute the fundamental groups of $Z$ and $W$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $P^{n}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Euclidean space and the real projective space endowed with their standard topologies. Let $p$ denote the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

(b) Let $Z$ denote the space $Z= \mathbb{R}^{3} \backslash \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid x,y=0\}$ with the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Set $W= Z\backslash \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid z=0, \, x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$. Compute the fundamental groups of $Z$ and $W$.

Could anyone give me any help on this question, my skills in topology are not great and I'm unsure how to start on this. I know the definition of a fundamental group but I'm not sure how to apply it to questions

Comment: Well, we have to start somewhere! Can you visualize the spaces $Z$ and $W$? If so, what do they look like? Or if not, can you describe these spaces in words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key property to use is that if $Y\subseteq X$ is a deformation retract of X then $\pi_1(Y) \simeq \pi_1(X)$.

I like to do the deformations in stages:

For $Z = \mathbb{R}^3 - \{z-axis\}$, we have $\pi_1(Z) \simeq \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2 -\{(0,0)\}) \simeq \pi_1(S^1)= \mathbb{Z}$. For example, the deformation from $Z$ to  $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is given by $f_t(x,y,z)) = (x,y,(1-t)z), 0\leq t \leq 1$.

For $W$, first deform $Z$ to a solid cylinder, minus the circle,say,$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1/2\leq (x^2 + y^2) \leq 3/2\} \times \mathbb{R}$ minus the circle; then to a solid torus minus a circle; then to a torus so $\pi_1(W) \simeq \pi_1(T^2)=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.